# Swift AVFoundation: Ending AudioSession causes Animation to lag

Tags: swift, animation, audio, swiftui, avfoundation

I have a Trainings-App where the user can set an interval time, for example 30 seconds.

**What I want to do:**

When the user starts the training, an animation starts. When the time is over, I play a sound and the animation starts all over again. When I play my sound I also want to duck the background music that might play form another app.

**The problem:**

The problem is that when I play the sound, the animation and the sound have a small delay. The animation stays in the end position from the first cycle and after a little bit less than a second the sound plays, but it should play immediately. After the sound was played the animation starts again.

This problem does not occur when I don't change the audioSession-Category back to `.mixwithOthers`. But I have to change it because otherwise the background music doesn't unduck. Or is there an other way?

**Code**

Timer and Animation:

```
ZStack{
            Circle()
                .trim(from: 0, to: 1)
                .stroke(colorScheme == .dark ? Color.white.opacity(0.08) : Color.black.opacity(0.09), style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 35, lineCap: .round))
                .frame(width: x - x/7, height: y - y/7)
            
            Circle()
                .trim(from: 0, to: intervallTimer.position)
                .stroke(intervallTimer.ringColor.convertToColor(), style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 35, lineCap: .round))
                .frame(width: x - x/7, height: y - y/7)
                .rotationEffect(.init(degrees: -90))
            
            VStack(spacing: 0){
                
                intervallTimer.time.inTrainingsFormat()
                
                Text(intervallTimer.currentEx)
                    .font(.system(size: 40))
                    .padding(.top, 20)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .lineLimit(3)
                
            }
        }
.onAppear{
    self.timer = Timer.publish(every: 0.1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
}
.onReceive(timer){ _ in
     Sound.playSounds(sound.wav)
     intervallTimer.position = 0.01
 }
```

Playing the sound:

```
class Sound{

static var audioPlayer:AVAudioPlayer?

static func playSounds(soundfile: String) {
    
    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: soundfile, ofType: nil){
        let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        
        do{
            try audioSession.setCategory(.ambient, options: .duckOthers)
        
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
            audioPlayer?.prepareToPlay()
            
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                audioPlayer?.play()
            }
            
            try audioSession.setCategory(.ambient, options: .mixWithOthers) //when I leave this line out the delay does not occur but the background sound stays quieter
            
        }catch {
            print("Error")
        }
    }
}



}
```

**Thanks in advance :)**

Edit: Working code for playing sound without lag

```
class Sound: NSObject, AVAudioPlayerDelegate{

var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?
let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

override init() {
    super.init()
    
}

func prepareAudioPlayer(soundfile: String){
    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: soundfile, ofType: nil){
        do{
            try audioSession.setCategory(.playback, options: .duckOthers)
            
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
            audioPlayer?.delegate = self
            audioPlayer?.prepareToPlay()
            try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(false, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
        }catch{
            print("Error - Coudnt create audioplayer")
        }
    }else{
        print("Error - Path not found")
    }
}

func play() {
    
    if let _ = audioPlayer{
        self.audioPlayer!.play()
    }else{
        print("Error - AudioPlayer is nil")
    }
}

func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {
    print("Did finish Playing")
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
        try? self.audioSession.setActive(false, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I'd consider loading your `AVAudioPlayer` and its content _before_ you need to play it. Loading from the file, preparing, and then calling play (on the next run loop) all takes time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of mistakes here. It looks like you're calling `playSounds` 10 times a second, which doesn't make sense. Normally you'd just call that one time without a timer.

Next, you're loading the file at the last moment, which takes some time. Ideally you should setup your AVAudioSession and AVAudioPlayer one time, ideally earlier in the program, not the moment you want to play.

If you want to duck others while playing, just set it once. It's not clear why you keep switching modes. Generally AVAudioPlayer will automatically activate the session for you. You may want to deactivate the session if you want ducking to stop. But you shouldn't need to keep switching modes unless you're playing different things with different needs.

You definitely should not be calling `.play` on background queue. It's asynchronous. That's definitely causing problems.

There's also no point in calling `prepareToPlay` and then immediately calling `play`. The point of `prepareToPlay` is in cases where you can queue up the audio asset earlier in the program and have it ready to play so that when you call `play` it'll be instant.

The key thing you want to do is dramatically simplify this. You have a lot of pieces that aren't needed (timers, setting session options multiple times, background queues, `prepareToPlay`). Take all of that out and get it working without ducking (it should be very short). Then add ducking.

Comment: Thanks! Now I call .prepareAudioPlayer() when I initialize my view and the delay does not occur anymore. But when I call the function the background music gets immediately quieter. But I only want this to happen when I play my sound. What do I have to change?

Comment: Use `setActive` on your AVAudioSession to determine when you want it to be active and when you don't. AVPlayer automatically will make the session active, but you can control it yourself manually.

Comment: Hey, I open a new question for the problem. Maybe you can help me :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75897649/swift-swiftui-deactivating-audiosession-causes-lag-in-ui

Comment: No problems. Yeah, this is the one place you do want another queue, but don't use `.background`. That means "this is extremely low priority, so low it's ok if it doesn't get run at all." You actually want `.default` or possibly `.userInitiated` if the user caused the transition.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I changed it to .userInitiated and now also use AVAudioPlayerDelegate. This way the lag is almost not noticeable anymore, even if it is still there a little bit, but bearable.